# Dual of a quadratic constraint

Tags: nonlinear-programming, quadratic-programming, duality, dual

This is my model.

\begin{align}
\min_x&\quad\sum_{e\in E} X_e p_e \\ 
\text{s.t.}&\quad\sum_{e \in E: T(e)=i} X_e - \sum_{e \in E: H(e)=i} X_e = \begin{cases}1, \;\text{if}\;i=s\\-1,\;\text{if}\;i=t\\0,\;\text{if}\;i\neq s,t \end{cases} \;\forall i \in I\\
&\quad X_e^2 - X_e = 0 \;\forall e \in E \\
&\quad X_e \geq 0
\end{align}

First, can I use strong duality?

If so, which would the dual of this problem be? I don't know how to handle the second constraint.

Comment: What are you modelling with your second constraint ?

Comment: Looks like a bad way to model binary variables (i.e., your model is a MILP)

Comment: Hi, I fix it, X is continuous. This is a 'simplify' model to ask for my complete model. The problem is that I have to put the second constraint for the nature of the whole problem, there is no escaping it.

Comment: All constraints are linear except the constraint $X_e^2-X_e=0$ which simply says $X_e$ is either 0 or 1, i.e. binary. Hence, you can remove that constraint and simply say $X_e$ is binary and solve this using a MILP solver. Solving it via quadratic constraints will not be faster or smarter.

Comment: Hi, I know that. But need the constraint for the problem to solve, I added to change the nature of the variable from binary to continous.

Comment: Why? Without context, most people will think you are on the path of doing something unnecessarily complicated and not bother to answer. Strong duality will not hold.

Comment: It is part of the problem context which is really long, in summary I need the problem to be continuous using that transformation.

Comment: You minimize $p^Tx$ subject to $Ax=b, x_i^2 = x_i$. Apply standard dual stuff (http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~cmcaram/EE381V_2012F/Lecture_12_Scribe_Notes.final.pdf for instance) with an added term for the equalitites. You will most likely not get anything particularly constructive, but 12.4 is the dual.